# Hierarchical SQL question

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I have a basic tree structure of entities.  The tree can be a maximum of 5 nodes deep, but may be N nodes wide.  I have mapped this relationship in table similar to what is shown below:

```
myID | myDescription | myParentID
```

I am starting out with a known object, which could translate to having a starting "myID".  Now I want to get all the child nodes.  Is there a way of getting all the child nodes in one statement?  This needs to include the children of my children, and going on down the tree.  I am using  Oracle SQL.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
START WITH
        myid = :id
CONNECT BY
        myparentid = PRIOR myid
```

Comment: @Eric: Correct, CONNECT BY is Oracle only hierarchical query syntax.

Comment: `@Eric J.`: absolutely. In `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL 8.4` you use `CTE`'s, for `PostgreSQL 8.3-` and `MySQL` read these articles in my blog: http://explainextended.com/2009/05/29/hierarchical-queries-in-postgresql/ , http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using another way to model your hierarchy if you want to retrieve all nodes in a single query. One very good, and common, implementation is the [nested set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) model. The article outlines how this is implemented in MySQL, but it can easily be ported to Oracle.

Comment: Its a cool model, but not advisable for concurrent updates on large amount of data. Adding a leaf could update all records in table. **If data changes rarely its a good advise.**

Answer (score 0):

A possible neat way to implement this is to add another field that contains the "path" to the record. Say the top record is ID=1. It has a child with ID=5, and it again has a child with ID=20, then the last record would have the path
/1/5/20
So if you want all child nodes of you top node you do

```
select * from MyTable where Path like '/1/%'
```

(sorry, sql server syntax, I'm not an oracle developer - but the concept would still apply)

To get children of the middle node

```
select * from MyTable where Path like '/1/5/%'
```

The neat thing about that solution is that you can apply indexes to the "path" field, so the statement will execute using only a single index scan making it very efficient.