# How to create parent child relation in query?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hierarchical SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336318/hierarchical-sql-question)

I have below records to maintain. It has parent child relation. I have one table and from that table i am going to build dynamic menu...So it has below type of records. Like a tree..One parent has two sub menu and two sub menu contains two or three menu...So how to manage it by inline query?

Here is my table structure

```
***ColumnName***
ID
MenuName
ParentID
URL
```

This will be data

```
    ID                ParentID
    1                      0
    2                      0
    3                      0
    4                      0
    5                      1
    6                      1
    7                      5
    8                      5
    9                      2
```

How to create select query to get parent child relation?? if anyone have any idea about this than please help me.

Comment: `select * from my_table` "gets" the parent-child relation. What do you want the result to look like and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) in order to achieve this?

Comment: @Ben: Not like that dude...what i am doing right now, I am fetching all the data without put any relation. I am managing by my code but i want it from inline query..got it?

Comment: Actually I did not get it. Can you please add an example to your question?

Comment: @user968441, I don't know about Ben, but I don't get it.  What do you expect to see?  That table holds your parent-child relationship.  What else are you trying to get?  Give us an example.

Comment: I'm sorry but no, the relation is inherent in the design of the table; that's the point of it. How you _return_ the data from the table is down to the SQL query used to retrieve it. Any response to this question will therefore be a guess unless you're able to tell everyone what you actually want...

Comment: I think this is a hierarchical table, and hence solvable with Oracle's `CONNECT BY PRIOR ... START WITH` syntax.  Which is already been well-covered in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+hierarchical+%22connect+by%22+prior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this

```
select t.id
      ,t.ParentID
  from table_name t
 start with t.ParentID = 0
connect by prior t.id = t.ParentID
```