# Getting all descendants for a given element in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, hierarchical-data

I have a fairly straightforward self-referenced table like the following:

**TABLE 1**

```
id      parent_id
1       NULL
2       1
3       NULL
4       1
5       2
6       5
7       2
8       4
```

I need to generate a new table where for each element, all their descendants are associated. See this example:

**TABLE 2**

```
element  descendants
1        2
1        5
1        6
1        7
1        4
1        8
2        5
2        6
2        7
5        6
4        8
```

Notice that `3` is not present because it doesn't have any children.

How can I achieve this using a stored procedure? I can get a direct parent-child relation, but I'm having a hard time getting all descendants for a given element.

(real world table is ~15k rows & ~7 level hierarchy, but level it is not predefined so lets assume is N)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hierarchical SQL question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336318/hierarchical-sql-question)

Comment: @Ben That's oracle, I'm working with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a recursive CTE.  MySQL now supports recursive CTEs, as described in the [MySQL Server Blog](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/).

Assuming a table named "self_ref", the recursive CTE would be something like:

```
with recursive ref(element, descendant) as (
select parent_id, id from self_ref
union 
select element, id
from ref as r
    inner join self_ref as s on s.parent_id = r.descendant
where parent_id is not null
)
select element, descendant from ref
where element is not null
order by element, descendant;
```

(This was written for Postgres, but the MySQL syntax is similar if not identical.)

Comment: Is this new in MySQL 8? I'm using 5.7

Comment: Yes.  If you can't upgrade, considering copying your data to a DBMS that supports recursive CTEs, doing the work there, and then copying the data back to MySQL.  A local install of Postgres could serve this purpose for you.